# Link Anchor tags to Form Controls Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-ui-router

I am kinda stuck on this issue where i making validation message to the user and if the user submitted invalid form a message should be shown at the top containing anchor tags with the form controls link. I am dealing with shared components so it would be very helpful if someone helped me to fix it.

ErrorComponent.html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let control of controls; trackBy: trackByFn">
  <ng-container *ngIf="formGroup.get(control.formControlName)?.invalid">
    <p class="govcy-mb-0">
      <span class="govcy-visually-hidden-error">Error: </span>
      <ng-container *ngIf="control.formControlName !== 'chassisNumber'">
        <a target="_self" href="#{{control.formControlName}}" aria-describedby="error_message_id" *ngFor="let error of control?.validations">{{ 'Common.EnterYourText' | translate }} {{ control.label | translate }}</a>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="control.formControlName === 'chassisNumber' && formGroup.get(control.formControlName)?.value?.length !== control.maxLength">
        <a target="_self" href="#{{control.formControlName}}" aria-describedby="error_message_id" class="govcy-anchor">{{ 'Barricades.ChassisNumberMessage' | translate }}</a>
      </ng-container>
    </p>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

FormControlsComponent.html
this is the html file where the form controls are placed into

```
<ng-container *ngIf="field">
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" class="govcy-form">
    <div class="input-wrapper govcy-form-control">
        <input 
        [type]="field?.type" 
        [formControlName]="field?.formControlName" 
        [readonly]="field?.isReadOnly" 
        [ngClass]="{
         'govcy-text-input': field?.formControlName !== 'code',
         'custom-input': field?.formControlName === 'code',
         'govcy-text-input-error': isFormControlInvalid(field, formGroup)
        }" 
        [maxlength]="field?.maxLength" />
    </div>
</form>
```

i have tried using the href and id approach but it is not working.
Thank you !